# Is there a way to assign global hot keys to go to the next/previous album in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

What is the easiest way to add ability to go to next and previous album (not track) using media keys with modifier key (like <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> or any of <kbd>⇧</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>)?

Is it possible without using additional applications?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.usingmac.com/2007/11/21/mac-os-x-leopard-200-productivity-booster-hotkeys

```
153 Option-Right Arrow  Select next album
154 Option-Left Arrow   Select previous album
```

Comment: I need global hot key.

Answer (score -1):

Version 0.86 of ByteController can move to the next or previous song globally. http://awil.no/bytecontroller

Comment: next/previous album, not song. I have media keys to move between songs.